# How to add the ''Facebook Like Button' ,so my viewers have to press like to see the rest of the content?

Tags: facebook-like

Well , like all bloggers we want sharing for our posts so we have more visitors. Well i have seen in plenty of blogs that someway the make us press a like button to see the content(especially photos and videos) . Can someone explain me and help me about how to to this in my own posts? did i add a Html Code or what? Please Help Someone :D thank you (sorry for any mistakes i am from greece)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to learn some JavaScript, and create a facebook application.
Once you have created a [facebook application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), you can use this [event subscription](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to then show the content:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        //show the content here
    }
);
```